# Metadata file 'xyz.dlll' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

**Description :**

I have small utility containing MVC project and 3 class libraries and all references are properly added in project and all debug check-boxes are checked under configuration manager but still Visual Studio is showing an error i.e. Error 32 Metadata file 'xyz.dll' could not be found.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: have you checked project dependencies and build order? I remember I had to remove and add reference to fix one of those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works. I did and it worked for me.

```
* Clean every project individually (Right click the project -> Clean).
* Rebuild every project individually (Right click the project -> Rebuild).
* Rebuild the startup project (Right click the project -> Rebuild).
```

If you have any references, remove and add them again.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a circular reference between your projects.

If all your projects are in one solution, try not to add references to dlls but instead add them as project references. You'll immediately get a messages on trying to add a circular reference. Checking them manually also helps.